# sharepoint 2010 item selection event on lists

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have read all the list events (and list item events) of sharepoint 2010, but it seems there isn't a way to get an event when a list item gets just selected (or double-clicked, or something like that)
I want a method that lets me open a new page when someone selects an item on the list, to display more information regarding the item
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Or just open the page in the same window, it doesn't have to be in a new window/tab. For example i have a list of projects, and when i click on one of them (double click would be better maybe), open this new page with all the details of the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. But by default, when you click on the title of the Sharepoint item, it opens the item details showing you all properties for that item. You can customize the display form as you need. Another options are:
1) Customize the ribbon and adda button which can display a page in a dialog box. See "Custom Actions" in Sharepoint SDK
2) Add a custom menu item the context menu of the item in the list and open a custom page showing the information you need.

Comment: Ashish what do you mean exactly with: "2) Add a custom menu item the context menu of the item in the list and open a custom page showing the information you need."? What is a context menu? Where is it?

Comment: Well, in SharePoint, you can extend the contxt menu for a document or list item entry in Document Library or a List respectively. It is also referred as "ECB Menu Item" in documentation. Please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394532.aspx for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the default `DispForm.aspx` page and add more Web Parts.

**Example** (it's SharePoint 2007, but the same thing can be done in SharePoint 2010)

[image]

By default, SharePoint 2010 shows item details in a popup dialog.
If you want to edit the `DispForm.aspx` page, you need to go to *List Settings* / *Advanced settings* and set *Launch forms in a dialog?* to *No*; clicking an item will now load a full page. You can edit this page (*Site Actions* / *Edit Page*) and add some Web Parts. These Web Parts will be visible on the full page as well as the popup dialog, so you can switch *Launch forms in a dialog?* back to *Yes*.

Comment: Title (linked to item) works as a clickable link. But obviously it just shows me the same details i can have in the columns of the list. What i need to do is create a page where i can insert this standard information and add other things such as a list of related documents. Anyway i got a solution: in my list i can create a hyperlink field, in which i pass the item id as an url parameter. This way in the page that opens i know which item has been clicked =)

Comment: Yeah it would be similar to yours! But how do yuo het there as a page? I mean, in SP 2010 when i click on the item title i get a small popup window, not an entire web page. WHere do i find this DispForm.aspx? Can i edit it in visual studio?

Comment: Woa it's great! I think this should work, let's see what does my chief think about it ^^

Comment: This solution would be ok, but we prefer to create a new button in the ribbon as suggested by Ashish Patel. Now i'm downloading the SDK, tomorrow i'll start studying how to do it. Thanks guys!

Comment: It seems i have some problems adding a new button to the ribbon. I asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930970/sp2010-how-to-create-a-new-button-in-the-ribbon